# Convert Numeric Reference Character to actual character

Tags: c#

I have a text that needs to be converted into an actual character, we use swedish characters but the data that we received are encoded into Numerical Character like this: `&#246; &#196; &#229;`
which suppose to be converted into normal characters like `ö, ä, å` this respectively.

I tried to search here but no luck and there was one though however they use python library instead so I can't convert it to C#.

Do anyone has a sample code on how to convert it to a normal character?

Comment: Have you tried [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Not yet, will try that...

Comment: Actually [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?view=netframework-4.8) may be better as it's part of the standard library, you wont have to add any dependencies to your project.

Comment: Thank you so much it works! +1 to you @AlphaDelta

Comment: @AlphaDelta - Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)` method can do trick for you or you can also use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string)` method Under Namespace `System.Web`.

```
var res1 = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#246");
```

OR

```
var res1 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&#246");
```